# Opengl deferred lighting shader

Tags: opengl, shader, deferred-rendering, deferred-shading

I just started to learning OpenGL 3.1 and I'm trying to implement deferred shading to my engine(framework?). I wrote simple shaders for first stage, lighting stage and deferred stage.
Lighting stage takes the diffuse color from deferred texture and saves it in lighting texture. Deferred stage draws the lighting texture. In lighting shader is a bug and scene is very strange. It looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1qerf2bmmtdqsw/screen1.png), and it should look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bj2uth2d5k2lq70/screen2.png). Lighting stage vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec4 vertex;

out vec2 position;

void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = vertex*2-1;
   gl_Position.z = 0.0;

   position.xy = vertex.xy;
}
```

Lighting stage fragment shader:

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;

uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;
uniform sampler2D positionTexture;

out vec4 lightingOutput;

void main()
{
    vec4 diffuse = texture(diffuseTexture, vec2(position.x, position.y));
    vec4 position = texture(positionTexture, position.xy);

    vec4 ambient = vec4(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 1.0) * diffuse;

    lightingOutput = diffuse;
}
```

That's what I render in lighting stage:

```
static const GLfloat _vertices[] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

And that's how I render it:

```
glUseProgram( programID[2] );

glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexID[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    vertexID[1],
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    0,                  // stride
    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionTexture);
glUniform1i(positionTextureID[1], 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuseTexture);
glUniform1i(diffuseTextureID[1], 0);

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );

glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexID[1]);
```

If you need all the code it's here www.dropbox.com/s/hvfe4v4pb1pfxb3/code.zip.

How to fix that strange problem?

Comment: "*I just started to learning OpenGL 3.1*" Then why are you trying to use deferred rendering if you "just started" OpenGL? Deferred rendering is a fairly advanced technique.

Comment: Because it allows me to easy adding lights and it's very flexible :)

Comment: Hmm... I don't have any idea how I did it but it works! I would write how I did it but I really don't have idea what was wrong. So sorry for the question.